# Kivy - start a video using a button

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I wrote in python, kivy, and kivyMD and i added a video widget.
I'm trying to make a video start every time a button is clicked, every time the video shoud be random between 2 videos. the random works - if i code it to start with the app, every time a different video start, but i want it to start only when the button is clicked, and every time - not just once.

i only found a wat to loop the video, or start it when the app is stating.

```py
def rnd_coin(self):
        if random.randint(0,2) == 1:
             return "videos/onDollar.mp4"
        else:
            return "videos/onLogo.mp4"
```

```py
            Video:
                source: app.rnd_coin()
                state: 'play'
            MDRoundFlatButton:
                text: "Tap to Start"
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I think you can use `setattr` with your `Button`:

```
        Video:
            id: vid
            source: app.rnd_coin()
        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Tap to Start"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            on_release:
                setattr(vid, 'source', app.rnd_coin())
                setattr(vid, 'state', 'play')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it partly works, it changes the movie and play it, but after the first run, it is starting again only if the source is changing. if the random function returns the same path it's not working, only if the path is changing the video start. I need it to start again if the path is not changing

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working. after doing what you said, i had a problem that it didn't play again the video if the path hasn't changed, but i solve it by adding setattr with stoping the video before changing the path.